# How to block outgoing traffic?

Tags: output, iptables, rules

I want to use iptables to block all incoming traffic, but on the other hand I want to whitelist all outgoing traffic. Currently, my iptables block all my outgoing traffic. How can I whitelist that?

iptables rules

```
iptables -F

iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s18 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 26666 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:26666

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

But it doesn't work:

```
curl http://google.com
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'google.com'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not blocking the outbound traffic; you're just blocking the inbound data that is the response (specifically, in this case, the DNS server's response).

Add this to the end to allow `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED` data to come in through the `INPUT` chain:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

[Here's](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=iptables+-A+INPUT+-m+state+--state+ESTABLISHED%2CRELATED+-j+ACCEPT) an explainshell.com link that will walk you through what that rule does.